# Recoil useRecoilValue outside component

Tags: reactjs

I want to build a JSON file based on a bunch of recoil values, so I created a function that fetches all the recoilVaules and returns a JSON out of it, and I call it from a component.

The thing is that it gives me an error for using useRecoilValue outside a component.

besides moving the function inside the component (which will make the component look bad because there are a lot of values) or passing all the recoilValue as parameters to the function (same), what more can I do?

This is the general idea -

```
const ReactCom = () => {
getJson();
....
}

const getJson = () => {
    let jsonFile = useRecoilValue(someAtom);
    return jsonFile;
}

Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a 
function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Comment: I think you already answered yourself. There is not much more to do, hooks must be in functional components.

Comment: @Jax-p thanks for the comment. I thought maybe there is a workaround or maybe a good idea about how to implement it due to the fact that I need the value only and not a setter...

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
const ReactCom = () => {
  const json = useGetJson();
  ....
}

const useGetJson= () => {
  let jsonFile = useRecoilValue(someAtom);
  return jsonFile;
}
```